# How to make input+label in a form appear one by one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can someone help me with my example on **How to make input+label in a form appear one by one?**

I have a `<form>` with some inputs and labels and i want to make them appear one by one. When the ENTER KEY will be pressed there the label #1 and the input #1 must dissapear and second label + input must appear.

My script + css and jss is up on the jsfiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/zApq4/

My js is:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

        // First Show the First Element & Focus it
        $("form.fieldContainer:first-child").fadeIn(500).focus();

        // Setup a transition handler:
        $("form.fieldContainer").keyup(function(ev) {

            if $('#nextButton').click(show_next);
            {
                ev.preventDefault();
                ev.stopPropagation();

                var _next = $(this).parents('form.fieldContainer').next('form.fieldContainer');
                _next.fadeIn(500);
                _next.find("input").focus();
            }

        });

    });
```

I guess i'm doing something wrong in my js but i can't realise what. Thanks to everyone

Comment: From a user experience point of view, this sounds like a very bad idea.

Comment: Just a heads up that in your CSS you have `form.fieldContainer`, when it should be `.fieldContaner`, or `form .fieldContainer`

Comment: What is `#nextButton` and `show_next`? That if-statement looks quite invalid btw.

Comment: Your selector is `"form.fieldContainer"` which selects the `form` with the class `fieldContainer`. However, you want to select the classes **inside** the form. The right selector should be `form .fieldContainer` (with the extra space).

Comment: This isn't something *new* and there's a reason why you don't see this all over the place.  Even pagination of web forms is a UX no no.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try following (is that what you want):

```
var $containers = $(".fieldContainer");

    // First Show the First Element & Focus it
    $containers.eq(0).fadeIn(500).find("input").focus();

    // Setup a transition handler:
    $containers.find("input").keyup(function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        ev.stopPropagation();

        if($(this).val() == ""){
            return;   
        }
        //if enter is pressed
        if(ev.which == 13){                  
            var _next =  $(this).parents().next();
            _next.fadeIn(500);
            _next.find("input").focus();        
        }
    });
```

working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/zApq4/3/

Or,

working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/zApq4/4/

i hope it helps.

Comment: Can you please help me with my problem... I need to press the submit button to show the second .fieldContainer, But also i need to hide the first .fieldContainer. @maverickosama92